# Unable to cast Python instance of type <class 'dict'> to C++

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I'm trying to pass dict[str, object] from Python to C++ to do some operations & keep object in C++ while it's being used.

```cpp
typedef std::map<std::string, py::object> dataMap;

void init_basicWindowMule(pybind11::module_ & m) {
    pybind11::class_<testObject, QObject> widgetClass(m, "basicWindow");
    widgetClass.def(pybind11::init<>());
    widgetClass.def("create", [](py::object obj) {
        manager = new testObject();
        manager->setData(obj.cast<dataMap>());
    });
}
```

```py
PyBindTest.basicWindow.create({"someStuff":testObject()})
```

What did I mess up?

Comment: What is the problem? You only describe a task and imply that it failed, but all details are missing. For example, provide an error message that would also allow searching for this.

Answer (score 0):

The code fails because you're trying to pass a `testObject` instance as a value in the Python dictionary. Pybind11 can't automatically convert a C++ object to a Python object, so you need to create a Python object from the `testObject` instance before passing it to the `create` method.

```
namespace py = pybind11;
void init_basicWindowMule(py::module_ & m) {
    py::class_<testObject, std::shared_ptr<testObject>>(m, "testObject");

    py::class_<testObject, QObject>(m, "basicWindow")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("create", [](const py::dict& data) {
            auto manager = std::make_shared<testObject>();

            std::unordered_map<std::string, py::object> dataMap;
            for (const auto& item : data) {
                dataMap[item.first.cast<std::string>()] = item.second;
            }

            manager->setData(dataMap);
        });
    }
```

To use the code, you can do:

```
data = {"someStuff": PyBindTest.testObject()}
PyBindTest.basicWindow.create(data)
```